# jquery and JSON how to I format a number as dollars and cents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, decimal, tofixed

I'm my fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/w2QHz/21/ , my search results show a 'number', but I need them to show as dollars and cents, or at least move the decimal two places as well as display any trailing zero.

I have tried several different mathematical equations, but I found out that my real trouble is displaying the trailing zero.  I have been trying toFixed(2), but couldn't figure it out.  Where to I put toFixed(2), or is there an easier way to get the results I want?

```
.append(th.clone().text(value.editions[0].price.high))
```

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/ftwSr/

Comment: What if the number was in cents?  Where would I put the 'divide by 100'?

Comment: if your prices are always in cents then; `(value.editions[0].price.high /100).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"$" + (+value.editions[0].price.high).toFixed(2)
```

See the documentation for [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
.append(th.clone().text("$" + (+value.editions[0].price.high).toFixed(2) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this,

```
parseInt(value.editions[0].price.high).toFixed(2)
```